# Using trigonometry to prove $\frac{a}{1-a^2}+\frac{b}{1-b^2}+\frac{c}{1-c^2}=\frac{4abc}{\left(1-a^2\right)\left(1-b^2\right)\left(1-c^2\right)}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> For the numbers $a,b,c$ with $ab+ac+bc=1$, prove that
>
> $$\frac{a}{1-a^2}+\frac{b}{1-b^2}+\frac{c}{1-c^2}=\frac{4abc}{\left(1-a^2\right)\left(1-b^2\right)\left(1-c^2\right)}.$$

This is a question from the trigonometric section of my textbook. But is it possible to use trigonometry here?

**Edit:**

Using the Dinesh Shankar's hint with $a=\tan\frac{x}{2}$, $b=\tan\frac{y}{2}$ and $c=\tan\frac{z}{2}$, the equation becomes

$$\tan x+\tan y+\tan z=\tan x\cdot\tan y\cdot\tan z.$$

But $z=\pi-(x+y)$, then

$$\tan x + \tan y + \tan \left(\pi-(x+y)\right)=\tan x\cdot\tan y\cdot\tan\left(\pi-(x+y)\right),$$

which implies

$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\cdot\tan y}.$$

Therefore, the original equation is also valid.

Please feel free to give another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You probably know that if $x+y+z=\pi$, then

$$\tan\frac{x}{2}\cdot\tan\frac{y}{2}+\tan\frac{x}{2}\cdot\tan\frac{z}{2}+\tan\frac{y}{2}\cdot\tan\frac{z}{2}=1.$$

Now, since $ab+ac+bc=1$, use $a=\tan\frac{x}{2}$....

I hope this help you.

Comment: using your hint I got $$\tan x+\tan y+\tan z=\tan x\cdot\tan y\cdot\tan z.$$ What should I do after that?

Comment: After some manipulation you will have $$\tan\left(x+y\right)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x \cdot \tan y}.$$

Comment: Hum. I got it. Thank you.